# 'onClick' event on div not happening when there are child elements present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a new website for myself, looks like this..

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="row1">
<div class="orange" onClick="itemLoad()">
<img src="img/game/wacky.jpg" width="140" />
<p><strong>A Day At The Races (2014)</strong><br>
3 x 8-bit instruments</p>
</div>

<div class="blue" onClick="itemLoad()">
<img src="img/game/dott.jpg" width="140" />
<p><strong>Back to the Mansion! (2013)</strong><br />
fl, ob, cl, bsn, xyl, vibes, vln, vla, vlc.</p>
</div>

.... etc etc etc.
```

**CSS** (all boxes have identical CSS except the background colour)

```
.orange{
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:#F90;    
display:inline-block;
margin:10px;
cursor:pointer;
box-shadow:#CCC 4px 4px 4px;
border-radius: 10px;
padding:10px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:1.5;
}
```

Basically, when you click on one of the boxes, it shows a content DIV telling you about that piece of music, based on the row it's in.

**JQuery**

```
function itemLoad(){
if($(event.target).parent().is("#row1")){
    $("#row1content").fadeIn("slow");
}else if($(event.target).parent().is("#row2")){
    $("#row2content").fadeIn("slow");
}
}
```

This function works absolutely fine when the boxes are empty, but when they have content in them as you seen in the picture, the function only runs when I click around the padding. I've never had this problem before. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Try your code in Firefox, and it will fail. Remember to always pass the event as an argument.

Comment: I think your problem is the condition if($(event.target).parent().is("#row1")). This will only pass if the event happens on the orange/blue div, not any of its children.

Comment: @adeneo is right, try your code with function itemLoad(event){...}

Comment: Thanks John C and Bojan, however I will be adding a parameter to itemLoad() later so how can I adapt the if statement to focus on the entire of the div?

Comment: To keep the same code you can check all ancestors of the clicked element, so you need to use parents() instead of parent()

Comment: Oh no, please don't use `parents`, at least do `$(event.target).closest('#row1').length`, but it's still the wrong way to do this.

Comment: Why should I not use parents()?

Comment: Well parents is slower than closest :) @adeneo is right.

Comment: @adeneo I'm not capitalizing everything - I use the odd capital so I can identify where one word ends and another begins..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.target` is the clicked element, and when you click a child element, that's what `event.target` is, so it's not consistently giving you the right element, or the right parent element, as `event.target` does not reference the element the event handler is bound to, but the element the event originated from.

Also, you're relying on the global `event`, which is not cross-browser.

What you want to do is use proper event handlers, and `this`

```
$('.blue, .orange').on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).parent().is("#row1") ){
        $("#row1content").fadeIn("slow");
    } else if ( $(this).parent().is("#row2") ){
        $("#row2content").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

It should be noted that there most definitively is a more dynamic way to do that, giving all the targeted elements the same class, and then fading based on index or position in the DOM, without targeting each element based on the parents ID.

Comment: I would eventually like to load dynamically load content into a div based on the box that was clicked i.e. itemLoad(x){ $(div).load(x + "html); } How can I adapt this to include that?

Comment: Not sure, depends on what `x` is ?

Comment: Take that first orange box, it's a composition for 'Wacky Wheels' so I'd like 'wacky.html' loaded into the content div.


itemLoad('wacky');

Comment: Use data attributes for that, much better.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I had in mind :)

```
function itemLoad(event) {
    if ($(event.target).parents().is("#row1")) {
        $("#row1content").fadeIn("slow");
    } else if ($(event.target).parents().is("#row2")) {
        $("#row2content").fadeIn("slow");
    }
}
```